# php mysql jquery javascript do not redirect if input is empty

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

what i'm trying to achieve is this:

if the input is empty, the user will not be redirected to the update.php page, but if the value of the input is not empty, the user will be redirected to the update.php with the corresponding id from the input that i am talking about..

so far i was not abLe to achieve this, and this is what i have so far:

i am working on the fiLes backend-search.php that feeds the hidden input field to my index.php page, and the main page which is the index.php page..

here are the relewvant codes:

(backend-search.php)

```
     if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM productslist WHERE brand LIKE ?";

 if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

 $param_term = '%'.$_REQUEST['term'].'%';    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $param_term);
     if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
         $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 echo '<p>'.$row['brand'].' - '.$row['wgtvol'].''.$row['unit'].'('.$row['generic'].') <input id="hiddenid" type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'" /></p>';
      }
 }
 else{
 echo '<p style="color: #FFFFFF; background: #b20101; font-weight: 700; "> No matching records found, brand name is still available.</p>';
    }
    } else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
       }
 }

 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 }
```

and the relevant codes from my index.php:

```
 <div class="search-box pull-left">
 <input id="search" class="m-top m-bot" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search by brand">
 <div class="result" id="result"></div>
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){

    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(inputVal.length){
        $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){

          resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
      } else{
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }
 });

 $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
 $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
 $(this).parent(".result").empty();

 var link = "view-or-add-stock-modal.php?id=";
     console.log(link);
     console.log($(this).text());
     window.location = link + $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val(); ;
      });
 });
 </script>
```

please bear with my code-writing as i am a screenreader user and i only rely on this technology as i have visual disability..

though i have tried this variation i have made, it still doesn't work:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){

    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(inputVal.length){
        $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){

          resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
     } else{
        resultDropdown.empty();
      }
 });
 $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
 $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
 $(this).parent(".result").empty();

 var link = "view-or-add-stock-modal.php?id=";
 console.log(link);
 console.log($(this).text());
 window.location = link + $(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val(); ;
 if ($("input:text").val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").length == 0){
 $('.search-box input[type="text"]').hide();
           }
      });
 });
 </script>
```

i am willing to accept any relevant explanation and fix if one can provide..

thanks in advance.. and please if the moderators are about to flag this as duplicate, i am looking for an specific answer and precise explanation so please do not flag this right away without completely reading the entire post.

Comment: I'll tried to reproduce your problem, but I'm at least not exactly sure what you want to archive. What I didn't understand is - when should the user be redirected to the "update"-page? (btw, is it the view-or-add-stock-modal.php file?) - atm it looks like this should only(!) happen when he clicks on one of the <p> tags returned by your ajax backend search - is this a correct assumption?

Comment: yes that is actually the "view-or-add-stock-modal.php" and not the "update.php".. hahahahahah

i am just not sure if what i am trying to achieve is achievabLe with my current codes.. of course with a LittLe bit of modification..

the user can click on any of the result which will be the "result p" and be redirected to the redirect page, but if the <input> which has a type of hidden is empty, the user should not be redirected to the page "view-or-add-stock-modal.php" and should remain on the index.php page and retain his input to my searchbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified in the question comments.

I would stick to your first solution and just change some code

```js
$(this).parent(".result").empty();

var link = "view-or-add-stock-modal.php?id=";
console.log(link);
console.log($(this).text());

var hiddenInputElem = $(this).find('input[type=hidden]');
//check first if the hidden Input Field is available and has a value
if(hiddenInputElem.length > 0 && hiddenInputElem.val().trim() != ""){
    window.location = link + hiddenInputElem .val();
}
```

The redirect happens immediately after you change `window.location`. Therefore you check before if the current clicked `<p>` Element has an hidden-Input (and if it's not empty). Otherwise no redirect will happen and the user stays on the current page - maybe you want to show some additional Info in this case.

And just a sidenote (my opinion) - Everything is possible - so if you want your code to do something it's archivable - but you need to know what you want :-)

Edit:
If you want to keep the user's input just remove this line

```
$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
```

Here you set the the textbox input to the value of the clicked `p` - in every case, and that's maybe not what you want

Comment: thanks @Evil_skunk!! it does not redirect anymore if there is no matching record from the backend-search page, however i wasn't abLe to achieve my other expected output if the user cLicks on the resuLt that has no corresponding id or no id at all, and that is to retain what he has entered into the searchbox and the user should stay on the index.php page..

Comment: big thanks @Evil_skunk, i never thought that wouLd be that easy.. LoLs

i reaLLy beLieve i need a to practice a Lot and improve my coding skiLLs.. LoLs

Comment: is there any way that i can contact you Evil_skunk / @Evil_skunk?